# How to prove $\sum_{i=1}^m \sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_{i}}E(\mathscr{N}_{i})\geq E(\mathscr{N}_{1})\sqrt{t-s}\sqrt{m}$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In Stochastic analysis lecture notes P6 by Paul Bourgade, about a total variation of Brownian motion is infinite, he writes that

$$E\Big( \sum_{i=1}^m \vert B(t_{i+1})-B(t_{i})\vert \Big)\rightarrow\sum_{i=1}^m \sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_{i}}E(\mathscr{N}_{i})\geq E(\mathscr{N}_{1})\sqrt{t-s}\sqrt{m} \, (*)$$
where $B(t_{i+1})-B(t_{i})\to \sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_{i}}\mathscr{N}_{i}, $ $\mathscr{N}_{i}$ are independent standard Gaussian random variables.

But I have no idea how to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to show that the last inequality of $(*)$ is true.

Comment: It's direct, just apply cauchy schwarz with $a_i = (t_{i+1}-t_i)^{1/2}$ and $b_i=1$, and note that $E[N_i]=E[N_1]$ for all $i$.

Comment: @Shalop It is $$\Big(\sum_{i=1}^m \sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_{i}}\times 1\Big)^2 \leq m\sum_{i=1}^m (t_{i+1}-t_{i})$$, isn't it?

Comment: Oops! You are correct, the inequality which Paul has written there is incorrect because it is facing the wrong way, and therefore his argument is wrong. There may be a simple fix though. Sorry about my confusion!

Comment: Here is one simple way to correctly deduce that the expected variation of $B$ on $[s,t]$ is infinite. Consider a partition $P=\{s=t_0<\dots<t_{m+1}=t\}$ of the interval $[s,t]$. Note that $$(t_{i+1}-t_i)^{1/2} = \frac{t_{i+1}-t_i}{(t_{i+1}-t_i)^{1/2}} \geq \frac{t_{i+1}-t_i}{mesh(P)^{1/2}},$$   and thus it is clear that   $$\sum_0^m (t_{i+1}-t_i)^{1/2} \geq \sum_0^m \frac{t_{i+1}-t_i}{mesh(P)^{1/2}} = \frac{t-s}{mesh(P)^{1/2}},$$ which clearly tends to $\infty$ as the mesh of $P$ tends to $0$.

Comment: @Shalop Thanks a lot! Maybe you post your comment below, I would choose your comment as the answer.